# select rows from two tables with all columns matched or at most one column unmatched

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

table A has 21 columns, 1st column is id, 2nd column - 21st column are d1-d20, 100k rows

table B has the same structure as table A, but it has 50k rows

find all data from table A and table B:

1. all columns are matched or
2. at most one unknown column is unmatched

Comment: I tagged sql server, I don't know why is is missing, how can I edit it?

Comment: When you say all columns you mean d1-d20 .. right? We are always matching by id and then we need to find out if all d1-d20 are matching.. if not we can have at most one non matching d1 through d20.. is this correct?

Comment: yeah, this is what I'm asking, I really dont know how to meet the condition "at most one column is unmatched"

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the CASE statements. The below should work for you. Try and let me know.

Tables t1 and t2. For simplicity of example I've kept the columns down to 3 only.

```
Select t12.myID
from
(Select t1.ID as myID, t2.*, Case when
 t1.d1 = t2.d1 and t1.d2 = t2.d2 and t1.d3 = t2.d3
then 'A'
else
  Case when
   Length(Replace(Concat(Case When t1.d1 = t2.d1 then '0' else '1' end
                        ,Case When t1.d2 = t2.d2 then '0' else '1' end
                        ,Case When t1.d3 = t2.d3 then '0' else '1' end),'0','')) = '1'
       then 'B'
   else
      'C'
   end
 end as mc
  from t1, t2
  Where t1.ID = t2.ID) t12
  Where t12.mc IN ('A', 'B');
```

Comment: I got it, case is helpful for filtering, but how to get id from t1 that satisfies this condition. by the way, can I use sum(case ... )=1 for the 2nd condition?

Comment: check now, you'll only get the IDs of 'all columns matching' OR 'at most one column matching'.

Comment: actually it's "all 20 matching" or "19 matching", but I got it, thanks!!!

Comment: Yeah, that's what you'll get.. typo in the earlier comment. What I meant was 'you'll only get the IDs of 'all columns matching' OR 'at most one column Not matching''. You can try to run in sql fiddle to test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c760ab/5

Comment: Don't forget to upvote/mark as answer if that is what you were looking for. If you need something else on this then post here.